# Can I set my cPanel to ban a specific IP address after a set amount of login attempts to my WP Admin area?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, cpanel, brute-force

I saw that one of the websites I'm managing has a lot of XML-RPC attack attempts. I installed the IP Geo Block plugin so it would block them after they exceed the limit set. In fact, this plugin lets me even see the password that was tried with each request. However, I'm worried that somehow this plugin is not the safest option. I am wondering if there is a way to ban an IP in the cPanel after like 5 login attempts in WordPress Admin. I know this would basically block the connection with the website altogether and since the IP Geo Blocker registered almost 7000 blocks in the past 2 days I think this would be the best option.

Comment: It looks like that plugin does not block at the firewall level, so its kind of useless, you could make a cron job which looks over the table it create of blocked ips and add them to iptables, also implement failed logins count, its not difficult.